# iFrame reload frame not page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

here is my code, I'm not sure how to reload the iFrame page(switch pages when the next/previous button is clicked) and not the whole page making their scroll bar set back to the top of the page, my users are finding it very annoying.

```
    <style>
p {
font-size:16pt;
font-color:cyan;
background-color:orange;
border-style:solid;
border-color:black;
border-width:3px;
width:128px;
vertical-align:middle;
horizontal-align:middle;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align:center;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
flag = 0;
SrcList = new Array("http://www.minecraft-index.com/3864-clearrealms/vote", "http://minecraft-mp.com/server/34632/vote/", "https://minestatus.net/98330-clearrealms/vote", "http://topminecraftservers.org/vote/19", "http://topg.org/Minecraft/in-378224#.Uu1YmHddWwE", "http://minecraft-server-list.com/server/197826/vote/", "http://www.planetminecraft.com/server/clearrealms-2643064/vote/");
function NextSrc(){
    if(flag < SrcList.length - 1){
    flag++;
    ChangeSrc(SrcList[flag]);
    }
    return false;
}
function PrevSrc(){
    if(flag > 0){
    flag--;
    ChangeSrc(SrcList[flag]);
    }
    return false;

}
function ChangeSrc(src){
    var iframe = document.getElementById('Vote');
    iframe.setAttribute('src',src);
}
</script>

<p><a href="#" onclick="PrevSrc()">Prev</a>  -  <a href="#" onclick="NextSrc()">Next</a></p>
<iframe id="Vote" src="http://minecraftservers.org/vote/96178" width="1080" height="795">
</iframe>
```

Comment: fiddle or link please

Comment: @chiliNUT www.clearrealms.com/vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the link. Change the link's `href` from `#` to `javascript:void(0);` so like

```
<p>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="PrevSrc()">Prev</a>
  -  
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="NextSrc()">Next</a>
</p>
```

Comment: NP, went through the same hassles of `href=#` and now I use `void(0)` every time

Answer (score 2):

well i think that you might be looking for this:

```
document.getElementById('Vote').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

true paramete = Reloads the page from the server.
false parameter = Reloads the page from the browser cache.
so this isn't what you want.

try this one instead in the

```
<head></head>
```

tags.

```
function Reload() {
var iframe = document.getElementById('Vote');
iframe.src = iframe.src;
}
```

and the html code like this:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="PrevSrc()">Prev</a> - <a href="#" onclick="Reload()">Reload</a>  -  <a href="#" onclick="NextSrc()">Next</a></p>
<iframe id="Vote" src="http://minecraftservers.org/vote/96178" width="1080" height="795">
```

Comment: Hey man, I tried your code, thanks for it but it won't even reload my page now, I believe I put it in the wrong place. Here is my before: http://pastebin.com/erndypCr Here is my after: http://pastebin.com/uBH3iLci The difference of your code is on line 38

Comment: Thanks a lot, both worked but chilliNUTS was much shorter, thanks for the help though, I appreciate it a lot. :)